# Ambiguity between Checkboard pose

Tags: ros, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
There is an ambiguity between the checkerboard pose in the upright position and the checkerboard pose rotated 180 degrees vertically(upside down). I am using camera_pose_calibration which relies on image_cb_detector for checkerboard detection for calibrating multiple cameras. Holding the checkerboard upright, one of my cameras assumes it to be upside down during calibration. Any suggestions on how to rectify this?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63195/ambiguity-between-checkboard-pose/) by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For camera calibration you don't need to rotate a lot the chessboard pattern. Just keep it as straight as possible and try to stick it to the edges to properly calculate distorsion parameters, then also put the chessboard in "prespective" to obtain a good skew ratio correction. Rotation of the chessboard pattern is not necessary.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-06-05**:
Actually i am keeping the checkerboard in the upright position but the corners are detected inverted i.e. the upper right corner of the checkerboard is detected in the lower right of the image instead of top left of the image. I just added a simple check which did the trick. Thanks.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-06-05**:
You could also use http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration#Camera_Calibrator and calibrate the cameras in pairs (if you have more than 2)

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-09**:
Can this package be used for multiple Kinects?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-01-12**:
Athoesen: I have not used Kinects with this package, but I suppose you can calibrate two kinects as if they were a stereo pair.